# Add a column to composite primary key that is also a foreign key in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have to add a column to a primary key in a table where the primary key is composed by two other columns. 
On top of it, the composite primary key of this table is a foreign in other tables and a column of the first table makes a composite key in a third table, so I need to update the other tables too. 
So to summarise, I have a scenario as follows:

```
Table A (column_A,column_B,column_C,column_D) Primary Key: (column_A,column_B)
Table B (column_E,column_A,column_B,column_F) Primary Key: (column_E), Foreign Key (column_A,column_B)
Table C (column_G,column_A,column_B,column_G) Primary Key: (column_G,column_B), Foreign Key (column_A,column_B)
```

While I'd like to achieve:

```
Table A (column_A,column_B,column_New,column_C,column_D) Primary Key: (column_A,column_B,column_New)
Table B (column_E,column_A,column_B,column_New,column_F) Primary Key: (column_E), Foreign Key (column_A,column_B,column_New)
Table C (column_G,column_A,column_B,column_New,column_G) Primary Key: (column_G,column_B,column_New), Foreign Key (column_A,column_B,column_New)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: And what would be the value of `column_New`? Or are the tables empty?

Comment: Tables aren't empty and `column_New` would have a default value on creation

Comment: So where is the problem? Drop FKs. Make your changes. Add new FKs.

Comment: The procedure would be: drop foreign key from all the tables, drop primary key from table_A, add column in table_A, add new foreign key to other tables, right?

Comment: Well yes. But don't forget to define the new primary key, before you define the new FKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the following steps:

Drop Primary and foreign keys (leaving table_b's PK untouched)

```
alter table TABLE_A drop primary key; 
alter table TABLE_C drop primary key; 

alter table TABLE_B drop foreign key FOREIGN_KEY_NAME_B; 
alter table TABLE_C drop foreign key FOREIGN_KEY_NAME_C;
```

next, add column_new everywhere...

```
alter table TABLE_A add column COLUMN_NEW <column_spec_here> after COLUMN_B;
alter table TABLE_B add column COLUMN_NEW <column_spec_here> after COLUMN_B;
alter table TABLE_C add column COLUMN_NEW <column_spec_here> after COLUMN_B;
```

next, rebuild primary and foreign keys...

```
alter table TABLE_A add primary key (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_NEW);
alter table TABLE_C add primary key (COLUMN_G, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_NEW);

alter table TABLE_B add foreign key NEW_FOREIGN_KEY_NAME_B (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_NEW) references TABLE_A (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_NEW);
alter table TABLE_C add foreign key NEW_FOREIGN_KEY_NAME_C (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_NEW) references TABLE_A (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_NEW);
```

Comment: the foreign key drop is only on table B and C, but overall looks good

Comment: yep, good catch...adjusted answer.  If it works, please mark answer as correct.